# Escaping colon ':' in element or attribute name in a xsd file (xml schema)

Tags: xml, xsd

my requirement is that I need to have a semicolon in the xsd tag element/attribute name.

Eg:

```
< xs:attribute name="some:name" type="xs:string" fixed="somevalue"/>
```

Is there a way to escape the `':'` char in the attribute name?

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, a colon and a semicolon are very different things: which is it you want? Colons are legal in XML names, semicolons are not.

Colons in XML names indicate namespaces.

You need to define elements and attributes in a schema document whose target namespace is the namespace part of the element or attribute name.

Within that schema document (say Doc-S), you declare the element or attribute using the local part of the name only. So if "some" is a namespace prefix bound to the URI http://some.uri, you create a schema document with `targetNamespace="http://some.uri"`, and within that you declare `<xs:attribute name="name"/>`.

Then in your original schema document you add an `xs:import` that refers to Doc-S, that contains a namespace declaration `xmlns:some="http://some.uri"`, and that references the attribute using `<xs:attribute ref="some:uri"/>`